# overfitting or not

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, machine-learning-model, data-science-model, overfitting

Hello so i'm building a classification model i train my on various models and these are the metrices so i want to know if ther's an overfitting or not

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Data Science!  You are expecting a lot of users here in sharing just screenshots with no context of what you're doing and how.

Comment: 2) For example, having done CV, it should be these metrics to compare with the test set. 3) How many classes? 4) What does the ROC look like? 5) Maybe output a table of results.

Comment: There are lots of questions on here on the topic of overfitting that should give you the guidance you need to answer this question.

Comment: @fswings what should i add to conclude if there's overfitting or, could u please guide me in discord or something else